# How can I pass schema model in route

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have defined a schema model inside a function of a controller file that creates a new collection in MongoDB. I want the model to be pass in route file. I had tried by doing `const Thing = mongoose.model('admin.companyName');` according to my schema , I am getting error :- `throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name); MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "admin.companyName".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)` on mongoose lib/ index file.

**My function inside the controller**:-

```
admin.save((err, doc) =>{
        if(!err){

            res.send(doc);

        //make copy to Company collection
            let arr = Object.keys(doc.schema.obj); //doc.schema.paths if I need same ID
            let Obj = {};
            arr.map(key => Obj[key] = doc[key]);
            var thingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({}, { strict: false, collection: admin.companyName });
            var Thing = mongoose.model(admin.companyName , thingSchema);
            var thing = new Thing(Obj); 
            thing.save();
            console.log(thing);
```

How will I pass var `Thing = mongoose.model(admin.companyName , thingSchema);` to my route file so that I can use in one of my **route** :-

**NOTE:-** ***The schema name of `admin.companyName` is not fixed and keeps on changing***

`const Thing = mongoose.model('admin.companyName');
Thing.updateOne( { emailResetTokenn: emailTokenn },{ $set: { verified: true }},(err) =>{ ......`

**EDIT:- routing file**

```
const express = require ('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const Admin = mongoose.model('Admin');
const Thing = mongoose.model('Thing');
const ctrlAdmin = require ('../controllers/admin.controller.js');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');


router.get('/verify',function(req,res){

    console.log('request recieved');
    const emailTokenn = req.query.id;
    console.log(emailTokenn);

   Thing.updateOne( { emailResetTokenn: emailTokenn },{ $set: { verified: true }},(err) =>{

    if(!err){
        return res.redirect('https://localhost/something.com/fw18/index.html'); 
    }
    else{
        throw err;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: monkey-patch the model on your express app & use them inside your route example: `app.db = mongoose.schema...` in your route `const model = app.db`

Comment: Every time you call `admin.save()` in your controller, you create a new collection.  so `Thing` is not really 'constant', it refers each time to a different model with different schema. If this is what you want, then it's fine. Where are you exporting your `Admin` model ?

Comment: @Marc you mean to say I must declare `app.db =mongoose.model(admin.companyName , thingSchema);` on server.js file ?

Comment: @MoadEnnagi Exactly, you are right. This is what I want. I am exporting my `Admin` model on router file only `const Admin = mongoose.model('Admin');`. In the place of  `Thing` .. it was `Admin` before  in `Admin.updateOne( { emailResetTokenn: emailTokenn },{ $set: { verified: true }},(err)`

Comment: Does `req.object` have any `Admin` attributes ? What are your getting as a request object in `router.get('/verify',function(req,res)` ?

Comment: @MoadEnnagi Yes right now `req.object` have `Admin` attr . I am getting all the key value details from `Admin`

Comment: Then you could query in `Admin` using the attribute you have in request as shown in the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the model `Thing`, you could use [mongoose.modelNames()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-modelNames) which returns an array of all model names created.

```
const Genre = mongoose.model('Genre', genreSchema);
const Book = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);

console.log(mongoose.modelNames()) // gives ['Genre', 'Book']
```

This will only give you the model names, you will need to figure out how to find the model you need maybe using the `admin` attributes.

**Edit** 
If you have an `Admin` attribute in you request object, you could, instead get the Thing model you need insite the route handler:

```
router.get('/:adminId/verify',function(req,res){
    console.log('request recieved');
    const emailTokenn = req.query.id;
    console.log(emailTokenn);
    Admin.FindOne({_id: req.params.adminId})
       .exec()
       .then(admin => {
          const Thing = mongoose.model(admin.companyName);
          Thing.updateOne( { emailResetTokenn: emailTokenn },{ $set: { verified: true }},(err) =>{})
       })
```

Comment: No , my main concern is how will I pass the model `Thing` in my route ?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Do you mean pass it as params ? what route ? can you show the code ?

Comment: I am in small confusion. I have no idea what will I find in `Admin.FindOne` . As you can see from admin controller , I have two collections one is `admin` another is being created according to whatever details are passed in `admin.companyName` . Earlier I was making one of the field in `admin` collection true. Now I want to do in same field name of `admin.companyName`.

Comment: You need to find the `admin` document you just modified, get its `companyName`, the companyName is the `Thing`s model name, so you assign that to `Thing`. What data are you getting in `req.query` ?

Comment: I am not getting anything in `req.query` when consoling it.

Comment: Ok, but, what's this : `const emailTokenn = req.query.id;`, what's `id` ?

Comment: Ok , In my `Admin` schema I have a field name `emailResetTokenn`. So I am using it to verify email id using Nodemailer. I am doing it like this way `randd = admin.emailResetTokenn; service=req.get('service'); linkk="http://localhost/something"+"/verify?id="+randd;` . Upon clicking the link , my default `emailResetTokenn `  false value change to true. Same thing now I want to do in my `Thing` schema as the model is same like you know.

Comment: You have to provide some data to your route, like you do here `+"/verify?id="+randd`, you need to pass some data in req in order for you to look for the `admin.company` which is the Thing model's name. Right now your route handlerdoesn't get anything (req is empty).

Comment: How can I pass some data . Any way to do verification on both the collection using one route ?

Comment: Yes you could, please show the route where you're doing the verification.

Comment: What I need to pass here `{/* query based on what Admin attribute you have in req */}`. Not getting  yet and why we need this again `const Thing = mongoose.model(admin.companyName);` ? As we have already declared it on controller. No more require to pass `Admin` query. Now I need only `Thing` query.

Comment: Pass the `adminId` in your route as shown in the answer, Thing in your code depends on the admin.companyName so you can't require it, declare it inside the route (verify).

Comment: you mean the id that mongo creates in the object `"_id": "5cb5a482e291a85bcb105cb1"` ?

Comment: Tried your answer and also included the url in nodemailer link `/:adminId/verifyAdmin?id="+randd` Still it is not verifying on click .. not redirecting as `adminId` is not mentioned in the link. So how will I include `adminId` in the nodemailer link ?